# Get sum of a row and column

Tags: sql, coldfusion, row, sum

So far i have made a table with products and its sums, according to a months, i am a new in this so i have a mistake: Variable total2_1_27 is undefined. i cant get the sums of products by month, i found so far by a row but couldnt get by column... so here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Tskak/1/ i just can't understand how do i define this total2, this line:

```
<cfset 'total2_#ddd_other#_#p_index#'=evaluate('total2_#ddd_other#_#p_index#') + #evaluate('alan2_#ddd_other#_#p_index#')#>
```

pls somebody help! and thank you all for the help!

Comment: I would definitely start with some refactoring. At least splitting data preparing and rendering would help to make it more readable.

Comment: u can have a look at the code from jsfiddle, there more convenient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use evaluate or put variable names inside quotes in a cfset like `<cfset 'blah_#x#' = foo>`.

Instead refer to variables like this:

```
<cfset variables['total2_#ddd_other#_#p_index#'] = variables['total2_#ddd_other#_#p_index#'] + variables['alan2_#ddd_other#_#p_index#']>
```

or

```
<cfset variables['total2_' & ddd_other & '_' & p_index] = variables['total2_' & ddd_other & '_' & p_index] + variables['alan2_' & ddd_other & '_' & p_index]>
```

This is assuming that the value is in the variables scope.  If it was in say session scope you'd refer to it `session['total2_' & ddd_other & '_' & p_index]`.  Also you can use += in CF8 and CF9, so this would be fine:

```
<cfset variables['total2_' & ddd_other & '_' & p_index] += variables['alan2_' & ddd_other & '_' & p_index]>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you are on SQL Server 2005 or greater. I am assuming you are on SQL Server because of the use of the DATEPART function.  I would actually tackle your problem using the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) command in SQL Server to take your list of totals by product ID and month and convert them to columns in your `CFQUERY`. It will greatly reduce the amount of code on the page and if you do the totaling in the query should reduce the code down to the `CFQUERY` and then a simple `CFOUTPUT`/`CFLOOP` around the table. It will get rid of all your lists and loops within your lists. Will make this page a joy to code instead of the headache it is now.

Comment: thank you, so i should rewrite the queries? i just don't know, does this PIVOT works on my server now, and i don't know sql that much to write it from the beginning, i think it will be better if i find answer here :)